# why i am getting wrong array count in php

Tags: php, arrays

`$array = array (0.1 => 'a', 0.2 => 'b');

echo count ($array);`

It overwrites first array element by second, just because, I used float with 0.

And hence output of above code is 1, instead of 2.

Why PHP round array index down to 0 ?

Comment: I didn't know you could use floats for index keys. Probably both indexes are turned to 0 and merged. EDIT: it is: http://ideone.com/LIC0E

Comment: Floats in key are truncated to integer.

See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4542234/working-with-an-array-with-period-in-key-value Convert keys to strings

Comment: You could have a string index of "0.1" but it creates a whole heap of subtle problems if you forget

Comment: Nothing is wrong with *PHP*, something is wrong with your *understanding* of PHP. When in doubt, consult the manual.

Comment: You guys has taken my question in wrong way, I mean to say that this is not the case with other programming language, why PHP handle float in such weird way. I already askeda question on float in php, please check for more details http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3148937/compare-floats-in-php

Comment: @santosh: 1) *That* other question you link to, OTOH, will be "weird" in *any* of the current programming languages, because `float` is a weird type ;)
2) As for "Why does a programming language work this way and not that way," the answer usually is "for historical reasons." I don't think that PHP's creators frequent this site, as they'd be in a position to explain their decisions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The array keys are interpreted as numeric, but numeric keys must be integers, Therefore, both float values are cast (truncated) to integer zero and `0.2` overwrites `0.1`.

```
var_dump($array);
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "b"
}
```

Make the array keys strings if you want to use non integer values:

```
$array = array ("0.1" => 'a', "0.2" => 'b');
echo count($array);
// 2

array(2) {
  ["0.1"]=>
  string(1) "a"
  ["0.2"]=>
  string(1) "b"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Only integer is allowed as key of the array.

See what we get if I print_r($array):

```
Array ( [0] => b )
```

However you can do like this:

```
$array = array ('0.1' => 'a', '0.2' => 'b');
```

Now print_r says this:

```
Array ( [0.1] => a [0.2] => b )
```

Answer (score 1):

Array indices cannot be floats. They must be either integers or strings. If you would try to `var_dump($array);` you would see that your array looks something like this:

```
array(1) { 
    [0]=> string(1) "b" 
}
```

You are effectively trying to set value for key `0` twice.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use floats as numeric keys. `0.1` and `0.2` both get converted to `0`

Either you have to use integers or strings. Therefore, your options are:

```
$array = array ('0.1' => 'a', '0.2' => 'b');
```

Or:

```
$array = array (1 => 'a', 2 => 'b');
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's see what the [PHP's own excellent manual says about arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) (emphasis mine):

> The key can either be an integer or a string. The value can be of any
>   type.
>
> Additionally the following key casts will occur:  [...]  **Floats are also cast to
>   integers**, which means that the fractional part will be truncated.

So, if you look at your array:

```
<?php
$array = array (0.1 => 'a', 0.2 => 'b');
var_dump($array); // let's see what actually *is* in the array
echo count ($array);
```

you'll get this back:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "b"
}
1
```

So, first your array is `{ 0 => 'a' }`, then becomes `{ 0 => 'b' }`. The computer did exactly what you *asked* it to, even if not what you *intended*.

Possible solution: pass the array keys as strings - there is no conversion to `int`, and it works as expected.

```
$array = array ('0.1' => 'a', '0.2' => 'b');
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use quote on non-integer keys

```
$array = array ('0.1' => 'a', '0.2' => 'b');
echo count($array);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are storing 'a' into the 0.1th element and 'b' into the 0.2nd element. This is impossible. Array indexes must be integers.

Perhaps you are wanting to use associative arrays?

```
$array = array ('0.1' => 'a', '0.2' => 'b');
```

Comment: Floats are also cast to integers, which means that the fractional part will be truncated. E.g. the key 8.7 will actually be stored under 8.

Comment: It is *possible*, but with the results seen in the question. Pedantry, I know ;)

Answer (score 0):

As per the php.net document on arrays for having keys:

> Additionally the following key casts will occur:
>   Floats are also cast to integers, which means that the fractional part
>   will be truncated. E.g. the key 8.7 will actually be stored under 8.

i tried [dumping](http://codepad.org/zVIut9pA) and interpreting the result... 0.1 and 0.2 will be interpreted as 0 and the latter overwrites the former, end result is that the array key remains 0 and value is set as b.

Hence there's nothing wrong with this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

its because floats are casted to integers, so the second entry overwrites the first.

Actually you are doing this:

```
$array = array (0 => 'a', 0 => 'b');
echo count ($array);
```

[Php.net Array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php):
"Floats are also cast to integers, which means that the fractional part will be truncated. E.g. the key 8.7 will actually be stored under 8."