# Unexpected output while using hashmap in PHP

Tags: php, hashmap

I am using php map for storing values in array map but when i increase the value for key, value of other key gets increased automatically.

Error while calculating

```
$myhashmap = array();
$myhashmap[0.2] = 1;
$myhashmap[0.1] = 2;
$myhashmap[0.1]++;
echo $myhashmap[0.1]."\n";   // 3 expected
$myhashmap[0.2]++;
echo $myhashmap[0.1]."\n";   // 4 unexpected
```

Like in above case in line6, i am increasing values corresponding to 0.2 but value corresponding to 0.1 gets increased. How can i fix this error?

Comment: Floats are also cast to integers, which means that the fractional part will be truncated. E.g. the key 8.7 will actually be stored under 8. http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php. related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4542234/working-with-an-array-with-periods-in-key-values

Comment: Do i need to typecast everytime?

Comment: no, you only need them quoted. `$myhashmap['0.2']` etc..